# Emulating Matlab fixed point number behavior in Python

Tags: python, matlab, serial-port, fixed-point, code-translation

I have a Matlab script that is old and decrepit, and I am trying to rewrite parts of it in Python.  Unfortunately, not only am I unfamiliar with Matlab, but the script was written some 5-6 years ago, so there is no one that fully understands what it does or how it does it.  For now the line I am interested in is this:

```
% Matlab
[rawData,count,errorMsg] = fscanf(serialStream, '%f')
```

Now, I incorrectly tried to do that as:

```
# Python
rawData = []
count = 0
while True:
    rawData.append(struct.unpack('f', ser.read(4))[0])
    count += 1
```

However, this prints out completely garbage values.  Upon further research, I learned that, in Matlab, %f does not mean float like it does in any sensible language, but fixed point number.  As such, it makes sense that my data looked like garbage.

Through trial and error, I have determined that I should be getting blocks of 156 bytes from a serial port.  However, I am unsure of how many values that translates to, as I can't find documentation that explains how large fixed point numbers are in Matlab ([this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ug/fixed-point-numbers_f20705.html) says they can be up to 128 bits, but that's not very helpful).  I have also found the python library [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html), and it seems like I would want to form them from the constituent parts (i.e. provide sign, digits and exponent), but I'm not sure how those are stored in the stream of data I'm getting.

Is there a good way of making a fixed point number from a binary stream in Python?  Or do I have to look up the implementation in Matlab and recreate it?  Perhaps there's a better way of doing what I want to do?

Comment: `%f` is IEEE float, not fixed point: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html#inputarg_formatSpec

Comment: Well that's odd.  [This](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.htmlfrrrefr4rr4r) claims they are fixed point.

Comment: Edit: Well crap, it looks like what I linked is for output.  I guess I'll have to figure out why my numbers look so off, then...

Comment: I just realized I linked the wrong `fscanf`, `serial.fscanf` is the right one: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/serial.fscanf.html